# Expression expected help android studio

Tags: android

```
package com.example.android.game;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), “gill.ttf”);
        TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView0);
        tv.setTypeface(font);
    }
}
```

just before "gill.ttf"); and after (getAssets(), it expects an expression, I don't know what to do and I'm a fairly new programmer :) thanks for the help

Comment: You have used double quotes are wrong.May be you have copied somewhere, please use double quotes from your keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from this part of your code:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), “gill.ttf”);
                                                      ^        ^ 
                                                These are your culprit
```

In other word: it's the `“`s you used in your code. The compiler doesn't understand this thus interpreted it as wrong syntaxes.

Here is how you should do it:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "gill.ttf");
```

Note how even StackOverflow's syntax highlighter doesn't even recognize the first example (the one you used in your code) as a proper `String` declaration and how it understands the second one (thus highlighting it with a red/maroon-ish color).

Hope this could help!

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry for the easy question, im a beginnner so yeah :) thanks again and have a wonderful day

Comment: how would i do this?

Comment: You should see a checkmark just below those vote buttons (up and down arrows) at the left side of my answer. Just check it.